# Pandas. How to read Excel file from ZIP archive

Tags: python, pandas, zip

I have .zip archive with filename.xlsx inside it and I want to parse Excel sheet line by line.

How to proper pass filename into pandas.read_excel in this case?

I tried:

```
import zipfile
import pandas
myzip=zipfile.ZipFile(filename.zip)
for fname in myzip.namelist():
    with myzip.open(fname) as from_archive:
        with pandas.read_excel(from_archive) as fin:
            for line in fin:
            ....
```

but it doesn't seem to work, and the result was:

```
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Comment: What if your ZIP file contains multiple .XLS(X) files?

Comment: you should edit your question to include the declaration of `myzip` instead of adding that as a comment.

Comment: @MaxU, it does not matter now. The goal is to solve the simplest case.

Comment: @IvanVodopyanov, why do you want to read it line by line - is it that huge that can't fit into memory?

Comment: @MaxU, I does not matter. First of all I want to open it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can extract your zip-file into a variable in memory and parse it using `io.BytesIO`:

```
import io
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas as pd


def read_zip(zip_fn, extract_fn=None):
    zf = ZipFile(zip_fn)
    if extract_fn:
        return zf.read(extract_fn)
    else:
        return {name:zf.read(name) for name in zf.namelist()}
```

Usage:

```
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(read_zip(r'C:\download\test.xlsx.zip', 'test.xlsx')))
```

Alternatively you can extract files from the zip-file to disk and parse them as a regular files.

PS there are tons of examples on StackOverflow, showing how to explode zip-file...

Comment: Nice work -- what is the zip file was a URL?   Apparently read_excel method can't accept a URL that is also a zip (with an embedded .xlsx in it)

Comment: @leeprevost, i'd first download such a zip file using `requests` and then use `read_zip()` function from the answer ;)

Comment: Anyway to do this for xlrs instead of pandas?

Answer (score 4):

Using zipfile

```
import zipfile

archive = zipfile.ZipFile('filename.zip', 'r')
xlfile = archive.open('filename.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(xlfile)
```

Comment: they are already using `zipfile`, the problem was trying to use `pd.read_excel` as a context manager

Comment: @Floydian, I guess your answer is the same as my question. Am I right?

Answer (score -1):

Simple way is:

df = pd.read_csv('path to file', compression='zip').

if u need u can to add extra atr: encoding = 'windows-1251' and sep = ''

Comment: This doesn't work for an Excel file, which was the original question.